# Rich 3D screensavers and Nvidia Optimus - the windows process which executes screensavers

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, screensaver, 3d, optimus

I want to use nvidia GPU tor run a nice screensaver, but it does not use my Nvidia GPU but the slower Intel GPU. As a result the screensaver has very low fps.

I need to show nvidia settings a program, to use nvidia GPU with it. Which windows process handles screensavers? how can I use nvidia GPU on my pc for screensavers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if your computer may use Optimus and use two video cards, one on-board and the other that of Nvidia. If that's not the case, please indicate your computer model and that of the Nvidia card.

If that is the case, one solution would be to go to the Nvidia control panel. In `Manage 3D settings`, click the `Global` tab, and set the prefered graphics processor to the Nvidia GPU.

Comment: Won't that affect programs such as Google Chrome which don't work well with the NVidia graphics acceleration?

Answer (score 1):

Screensavers are pretty much just renamed executables - with the filenames foo.scr which are launched by some process. I assume you installed the screensavers yourself and would know where they are- else they seem to be in c:\windows\system32 in windows XP `C:\Windows\winsxs\` in a folder with some name like `x86_microsoft-windows-bubbles_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_7085b0272833ba88`in windows 7. You *might* be able to set that specific screensaver to run on that videocard as you would with a game by specifically setting the scr file to run on on the discrete card .